# The NVM4W symlink was not found in the PATH environment variable

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm

I am trying to use Node 18.16.0 with NVM but NVM keeps telling me that Node installations are invalid. And I don't have administrative rights but I can edit env variables of my own account in Windows.

```
PS C:\tools\nvm> .\nvm.exe install 18.16.0
Downloading node.js version 18.16.0 (64-bit)...
Extracting node and npm...
Complete
npm v9.5.1 installed successfully.


Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 18.16.0
PS C:\tools\nvm> .\nvm.exe use 18.16.0
node v18.16.0 (64-bit) is not installed.
PS C:\tools\nvm> .\nvm.exe debug
B0060417 is not using admin or elevated rights.

Windows PowerShell
Windows Version: 10.0 (Build 19045)

Windows Developer Mode: UNKNOWN (user cannot read registry)

NVM4W Version:      1.1.12
NVM4W Path:         nvm.exe
NVM4W Settings:     c:\tools\nvm\settings.txt
NVM_HOME:           c:\tools\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK:        c:\tools\nvm\nodejs
Node Installations: .

Total Node.js Versions: 1
Active Node.js Version: none
(run "nvm use <version>" to activate a version)
NVM_SYMLINK does not exist yet. This is auto-created when "nvm use" is run.

PROBLEMS DETECTED
-----------------
The NVM4W symlink (c:\tools\nvm\nodejs) was not found in the PATH environment variable.

The following Node installations are invalid (missing node.exe): v18.16.0 - consider reinstalling these versions


Find help at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Common-Issues
```

What I am doing wrong?